# How to type hint specific objects in function argument

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, types, type-hinting

Suppose I have some function:

```
const someFunc = (input) => {// do something}
```

Where I know the input is an object that will have the property `thing`, ie. in the function I might check what `input.thing` is. How do I type hint the function when I declare it? I tried something like:

```
const someFunc = (input: { thing: string }) => {// do something}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works just fine. You are declaring the first argument is an object with `thing` as a required string.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBFMBbApgMQK4RHAvHACgEsIAHDGALjgG84YALEgc2tgCcW4BfASjwB8tYHFFxw0MABsUAOilhmxMhVmMWvANzBuwRKkzYCNdRFZwA5AxRSFFvsCA

```
const someFunc = (input: { thing: string }) => {
}
```

It can be helpful to work it out with a type instead of inline, just because inline types look kind of like destructuring.

```
type Input = {
    thing: string
}
const someFunc = (input: Input) => {}
```

You might want to allow other keys, but require `thing` in which case you can add `[key: string]: any` to your object.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out the error I had was because in an upstream function I did not have the same type hinting for `input`.